# ClickOnce problem with Update and the Query String

Tags: .net, clickonce, query-string

I'm working on a ClickOnce deployment where the application accepts a query string parameter. The problem is, ClickOnce is seeing the query string as a different URL so when I try to launch the application again without the query string or with a different query string I get the error saying it was installed from another location.

Here is the exact error.

> You cannot start application Sample Deployment Application from location http://localhost:52997/SampleApplication.application?version=2009.8.0.7 it is already installed from location http://localhost:52997/SampleApplication.application?version=2009.8.0.6. You can start it from location http://localhost:52997/SampleApplication.application?version=2009.8.0.6 or you can uninstall it and reinstall it from location http://localhost:52997/SampleApplication.application?version=2009.8.0.7. If you reinstall the application, be aware that you might lose any customizations that you made to the application.

From what I've been able to find, this was an issue with .NET 2.0 SP1 a couple years ago and is supposed to be resolved now. I don't have .NET 2.0 SP1 installed, just .NET 3.5 sp1 which came with Win 7. Is this a known issue or is there something strange going on in my deployment setup?

Edit: I've also tried the hotfix referenced in this (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952677) kb article, but was unable to install it since I didn't have .NET 2.0 SP1 installed.

Edit 2: More details... I'm trying to do the install via InPlaceHostingManager. The install works the first time with the query string variables, but doesn't work again unless the variables are the same. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a problem between the version and query strings.

Try runing it with only one version 6 or 7 installed. 
Then try switching the query string. If nothing new happend you should reports this bug!